# How to copy cached video from browser?

Tags: javascript, python

Is it possible to copy cached video data from a browser after the video finishes loading? I would like to use python or javascript.

Comment: What have *YOU* tried so far?

Comment: The only work-around I can think of is a bit kludgy...to use soundflower (Mac OS) to record directly. Don't know much else, so really looking for guidance, either specific or general.

Comment: Can you maybe clarify whether you want to load from the memory or from the disc?

Comment: I want to load from memory. Any ideas or direction?